# findViewById return null using parameter of OnClick method of OnClickListener interface

Tags: java, android

my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new Click());

}
```

my class witch implements OnClickListener

but on method Click of "Click" class.. the parameter View v.. dont work.
using method findViewById.. always return null :(

any help?

```
    public class Click implements View.OnClickListener
{       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        TextView view = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.resultado);
        EditText textoEdit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.campo_texto);

        String texto = textoEdit.getText().toString();
        view.setText("Obrigado " + texto);  
    }
}
```

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Is Click an inner class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `View v` references your button. That button view does not contain an element with `R.id.resultado`. Try `v.getRootView()`.

Comment: @RafaelF. While `v.getRootView()` will work, `findViewById` is an expensive operation as it must traverse the entire view tree.  You should only do it once in `onCreate` and save references to the views so you can talk to them later.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A Button doesn't have any child views, thus no view will be found when you call `findViewById`.  The `View v` parameter is the view that generated the touch event.  If you want to talk to the `TextView` and `EditText` in your layout, you should find them in `onCreate` and store them as class members.

Try:

```
TextView mTexto;
EditText mTextoEdit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new Click());

    mTexto= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);
    mTextoEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo_texto);
}
```

And in your listener:

```
public class Click implements View.OnClickListener
{       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        String texto = mTextoEdit.getText();
        mTexto.setText("Obrigado " + texto);  
    }
}
```